# Start Virtual Machine directly when booting (Virtual Box)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am behaving very stupid I feel. This question will receive downvotes.

I've installed an ubuntu iso via virtual box, but I want to fully start the ubuntu installation when booting the pc. Right now I can only use ubuntu within windows via a virtual box start.
I thought it would add "Launch Ubuntu" as a start option when booting the pc. On my old pc it did that (I'm not sure though if I used virtual box then or another tool.)
Is such thing not possible with virtual box?
It feels kinda odd to use Ubuntu within a windows window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the command-line tool [VBoxManage](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp90667008) to start a VM. Write a batch script and put it into autostart.

```
@echo off
"%ProgramFiles%\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" startvm "my-vm-name"
```

**Edit:** Now I understand your issue. You are mixing up virtual machines and side by side installations. Nevertheless, you can scale your vm to fullscreen with <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and it will come back in fullscreen next time.

Comment: you're right. I confused this, on my old pc I had installed ubuntu as a parallel OS. I'll do this again. Thanks anyway!